# Connect to RShiny app through phone by localhost

Tags: http, shiny, localhost, ip

I'm developing an app that I will be used mainly on phones, so I need to connect to it through the localhost. Computer and phone are in the same WiFi.
I have the app running locally, not in an Shiny server, just through Rstudio.

I have tried `runApp(port = 8080)` which, in the computer lets me access through the browser by `localhost:8080`, the app works.

However when I try to access in my phone the same I get a `localhost refused to connect` `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I have very little knowledge of networks, so that's why this is bugging me so much.

Comment: Are you using the local ip to connect from the phone, it should be something like 192.168.x.xxx and not 127.0. 0.1.

Comment: Yes, actually connecting that way it works. Hoewever, I'm trying to use the package shinysense which needs to run on localhost. So 192.168.x.XXX:8080 works but localhost:8080 does not.

Comment: @CodingBiology - *localhost is a hostname that refers to the current device* - Please check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost). Accordingly your phone has it's own loopback (or localhost) and can't access your PCs loopback.